# QML image clicked pixel

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

I have an image which is loaded into a quick map item, well I just want to find pixels row and column when user clicks on image, how can I get it?
thanks

here is my code

```
MapQuickItem{
    id:yes
    anchorPoint.x: image.width/10
    anchorPoint.y: image.height/10
    zoomLevel:1
    //width: 1
    //height: 1
    sourceItem:  Image {
       id:image
       asynchronous:true
       opacity: 80
       source: "qrc:/../../../../../Desktop/1.png"
       transformOrigin: Item.Center
       rotation: 0
       scale: 0.25
       //width: 500
       //height: 200
       sourceSize.width: image.width/2
       visible: false
       //sourceSize.height:100
    }
    coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the pixel of the original image or the image shown?

Comment: @eyllanesc do they have any differences? which one can I get?

Comment: If you notice in your code you have placed the following: sourceSize.width: image.width/2, So that image has been distorted.

Comment: Do you want to get only the position of where you click or you want the colors too? If you want the position: what position do you require, that of the source or the visual?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want the row and column of clicked pixel of source image, I dont need its colors yet.

Comment: You need the pixel position or you want the geographic position. The task you say is not simple.

Comment: @eyllanesc I can get grographic position, but I want pixel position in image, which row and column it is located

Comment: If the size of the image they display does not match the actual size of the image is impossible since to be distorted a set of real pixels represent a single visual pixel or vice versa whether you have enlarged or reduced.

Comment: For example let's say that the image is originally 400 * 400 but I show it as a 10 * 10 image, then 1 pixel of the visual image corresponds to 40 * 40 of the original image.

Comment: @eyllanesc well, so first of all we must show image in real size right?well how can we get clicked pixel location when it is show in real size?

Comment: add: `MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                
                console.log(mouse.x + " "+ mouse.y)
            }
        }` inside of Image

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, but it seems it does not return pixel row and column as they are integer values, it returns double values.

Comment: Are you sure? I get the following: `qml: 237 113
qml: 101 92
qml: 100 105
qml: 98 111
qml: 154 111
qml: 213 111
qml: 125 107`

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, I don't know why this is happening, can you share your code?So I can try with yours

Comment: @eyllanesc this is one example of output qml: 300.69747172264204 181.14527650058574

Comment: Share your code through github or gist to see what the error is.

Comment: @eyllanesc here you are:https://gist.github.com/am2222/057af8eb729a76b4f09c818de1d0ad24

Comment: Instead of adding inside the Image add it inside MapQuickItem.

Comment: @eyllanesc it seems it is not returning images pixel location. it is returning sth else. As When I click outside of image it also returns a value

Comment: @eyllanesc it seems putting MouseArea in Image tag works, I just have to round its value